# Open an HTML page in a pfd using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am trying to export the contents of an HTML file "Load.htm" in a pdf format using another HTML "Basic.htm" which is having a javascript.

### Load.htm

```
<html>
   <head>  
      <script type="text/javascript">        
            function sayHello() {
               document.write("Hello");
            }       
      </script>     
   </head> 
   <body onload="sayHello()">
<div id="divExport">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Basic.htm

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsPDF</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sprintf.js"></script>   
</head> 
<body>
<a href="javascript:demo4()">Run Code</a>
<script type="text/javascript">                 
function demo4() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();              
     var source = $('#divExport').htm();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(
                source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                0.5,    // x coord
                0.5,    // y coord
                {
                    'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });
            doc.output('dataurl')
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But after running the basic.html I am not able to get the output of the Load.htm in pdf format. I am thinking i have not included the HTML file load.htm in basic.htm . Is this correct ? I am not able to find why its not showing in pdf format :( . Do I need to add anything  ?

Comment: Have you tried opening  "Load.htm" in an iframe element (or window even) to see if you can access the content of `#divExport'` as a first step?

Comment: No but i tried to put an alert window after the line " var source = $('#divExport').htm();" but it was not showing. I am feeling that the load.htm file is not accessible .

Comment: Where the load.html is being loaded in Basic.htm? and you are accessing its element via $('#divExport')

Comment: @Savaratkar : I amm not able to load the load.htm file in basic.htm file :(

Comment: Then load it with a ajax call, get the html content and put it in 'doc.fromHTML( source'

Comment: Can you please redirect me to an example where i can see , actually i am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF is an open-source library for generating PDF documents using nothing but Javascript. You can use it in a Firefox extension, in Server Side Javascript and with Data URIs in some browsers.

```html
http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example of jsPDF</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script>
        function demoFromHTML() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
            // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
            source = $('#customers')[0];

            // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
            // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
            // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
            // (class, of compound) at this time.
            specialElementHandlers = {
                // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
            // 'inches' in this case
            pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins);
        }   
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="customers">
        <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="20%">
                    <col width="20%">
                        <col width="20%">
                            <col width="20%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr class='warning'>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Chinna</td>
                    <td>1,363,480,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>19.1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>India</td>
                    <td>1,241,900,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>17.4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>United States</td>
                    <td>317,746,000</td>
                    <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                    <td>4.44</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Indonesia</td>
                    <td>249,866,000</td>
                    <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                    <td>3.49</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brazil</td>
                    <td>201,032,714</td>
                    <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                    <td>2.81</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i want to load an HTML file which is outside another HTML file